# php Get JSON from URL

Tags: php, json, api

There is an API that result is for example like this:

```
// 20190920173100
//api.opencagedata.com/geoc

{
  "documentation": "https://opencagedata.com/api",
  "licenses": [
    {
      "name": "see attribution guide",
      "url": "https://opencagedata.com/credits"
    }
  ],
  "rate": {
    "limit": 2500,
    "remaining": 2493,
    "reset": 1569024000
  },
  "results": [
    {
      "bounds": {
        "northeast": {
          "lat": 51.9528202,
          "lng": 7.6325938
        },
        "southwest": {
          "lat": 51.9525445,
          "lng": 7.6323594
        }
      },
      "components": {
        "ISO_3166-1_alpha-2": "DE",
        "ISO_3166-1_alpha-3": "DEU",
        "_type": "building",
        "city": "Münster",
        "city_district": "Münster-Mitte",
        "continent": "Europe",
        "country": "Germany",
        "country_code": "de",
        "county": "Münster",
        "house_number": "7",
        "neighbourhood": "Josef",
        "political_union": "European Union",
        "postcode": "48153",
        "road": "Friedrich-Ebert-Straße",
        "state": "North Rhine-Westphalia",
        "state_district": "Regierungsbezirk Münster",
        "suburb": "Innenstadtring"
      },
      "confidence": 10,
      "formatted": "Friedrich-Ebert-Straße 7, 48153 Münster, Germany",
      "geometry": {
        "lat": 51.9526599,
        "lng": 7.632473
      }
    }
  ],
  "status": {
    "code": 200,
    "message": "OK"
  },
  "stay_informed": {
    "blog": "https://blog.opencagedata.com",
    "twitter": "https://twitter.com/opencagedata"
  },
  "thanks": "For using an OpenCage API",
  "timestamp": {
    "created_http": "Fri, 20 Sep 2019 13:01:02 GMT",
    "created_unix": 1568984462
  },
  "total_results": 1
}
```

I want to use the above data.

I tried the following code:

```
$adress  = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api...."));

$detail = $adress ->rate->limit;
```

and it is ok

The problem is when I use this code to get results data it is null for example

```
$adress  = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api...."));

$detail = $adress ->result>formatted;
```

I guess that it is because of the object and array

Comment: Your json has __no__ `result` property.

Comment: "result" != "results"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Don't use [file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/file_get_contents) function** **(This function reads entire file into a string)**

Because a URL can be used as a filename with this function if the [fopen wrappers](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) have been enabled only as described [here](https://www.php.net/file_get_contents). That is because sometimes this is closed (depending on your host, like shared hosting) and because of that, your application will not work.

**So my best suggestion is to use [curl()](http://php.net/curl) (Client URL)**

So according to your case you are requesting data from the API. So, we can use the `GET` method to request data with [curl()](https://www.php.net/curl) as follows with some headers,

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api....",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, // To get actual result from the successful operation
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30, // Set maximum time the request is allowed to take (in seconds)
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1, // Specify HTTP protocol version to use
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET", // Here the request method
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array( // Set custom HTTP headers
    "cache-control: no-cache"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl); // Here you will get the response after executing
$error = curl_error($curl); // Return a string containing the last error for the current session

curl_close($curl); // Close the cURL session
```

So now the response comes back in a [JSON](http://www.json.org/) object. Now you can use [json_decode()](https://www.php.net/json_decode) to put this into a usable object or array as you already did this.

```
$response = json_decode($response, true); // Because of true, it's in an array
```

As [will](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10513828/will) already answered in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58029399/8440358), unlike `rate`, the `results` object is an array containing your data. So you have to change your `result` to `results[0]` in order to read the `formatted` data.

```
$detail = $response->results[0]->formatted;
```

Comment: thanks for helping me about  file_get_contents  it is helpful

Comment: Pleased to know it helped.

Answer (score 0):

`$results` is an array, so you have to do : `$detail = $adress ->results[0]->formatted;`

Comment: you are right thanks